# how to make line graph

Tags: javascript

I want to make line graph with the use of javascript.

Can anyone tell me how I get this?

Answer (score 1):

have a look at this http://www.rgraph.net/

Answer (score 1):

as you have tagged for Android, I guess you want to make charts in Android. Try this
http://code.google.com/apis/chart/

http://www.achartengine.org/

http://androidplot.com/wiki/Home

Answer (score 0):

I've used [flot.js](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) - it's very good and well documented. There's also [g.Raphael.js](http://g.raphaeljs.com/), but I don't know if it's still being developed, and there are no docs whatsoever.